# php preg_match matching wrong subjects?

Tags: preg-match

I really don't understand why, but PHP preg_match is matching wrong subjects in certain ones.

For instance, in this 4 lines, i expect to get "match 2" as output, but i get all as matched instead (match 1 through 4)

```
if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'arnesdemanoTh.php'))
echo 'match 1';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'arnesdemanoTh.swf'))
echo 'match 2';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'arnesdemanoTh1.gif'))
echo 'match 3';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'arnesdemanoTh2.gif'))
echo 'match 4';
```

In this case, i get "match 2" as output, just as expected

```
if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'bang.php'))
echo 'match 1';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'bang.swf'))
echo 'match 2';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'bang1.gif'))
echo 'match 3';

if (preg_match("/.bin|.d64|.dcr|.gb|.gbc|.htm|.html|.nes|.prg|.sna|.swf|.z80/i", 'bang2.gif'))
echo 'match 4';
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the **"."** (dot) by putting a backslash before it, **ex \.**

```
$filename = "dvdrip.bin"

preg_match_all('/(\.bin|\.d64|\.dcr|\.gb|\.gbc|\.htm|.html|\.nes\|.prg|\.sna|\.swf|\.z80)/i', $filename, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$match = $match[1][0];

echo $match // echo's ".bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your periods, `\.` instead of `.`. Otherwise the `.` matches any letter, so "arnes" matches `.nes`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the "." since it will match any character. so instead of ".bin" use \.bin. in the first set of lines, the name of the file matches with .nes.